# Find the combination algorithm

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Once a month, Jerry visits the restaurant that he owns. Being paranoid that someone will steal his fortune, on each visit he changes the combination to his personal safe, which is hidden in the back part of the managers' office.

---

On each update, Jerry uses the next number in a numerical pattern that he has been aware of for years, and is very confident that no one else will figure out. Each time, he jots the previous combination down on a sheet of paper, which is taped to the side of the safe, to remind him where he is in the sequence.

---

The safe has a simple, 10-button keypad, like below, and can be programmed to accept combinations from length 1 to length 15. After 3 failed attempts in a row to open the safe, a text will be sent to Jerry's phone. Therefore, guessing is not a great idea.

[image]

---

After some time, the restaurant managers find the small piece of paper taped to the safe, and figure out that the numbers are the previous combinations, and assume that a pattern or sequence of some kind is being followed. They are bored and would love to break into the safe, if only for the challenge. However, they have yet to be able to find the pattern.

Here is the list of previous combinations:

> 1
>   8
>   41
>   208
>   1041
>   5208
>   26041
>   130208
>   651041
>   3255208
>   16276041
>   81380208
>   406901041

**What is the current combination?**

Hint #1:

> Eventually, Jerry's algorithm will produce combinations that are too long (>15 digits), but for now this works.

Hint #2

> The sequence has nothing to do with letters or alphabets or changing bases, and nothing is encrypted.

Comment: Does the pattern relates to the button positions in the picture you've shown? :D

Comment: @Alex No. I just tried to find the most basic keypad. The number positions have no significance.

Comment: Thanks @JLee, I figure I should ask before going deep into drawing arrows and stuff on the picture

Comment: I kind of think that number-sequence and letter-sequence puzzles like this need their own site, because I think they really annoy most people, and get down-voted a lot, unless they incorporate other puzzle elements.

Comment: It doesn't really annoys me (you've my upvote!), but it does make me scratch my head / open up excel and feels likes a dummy (esp when someone else got it within 2 minutes!)

Comment: OK, I just signed back on to delete this question, because the way it was solved was not the way that I intended, although it was also correct, and that other way just wasn't that interesting, making this puzzle, in my eyes, uninteresting. I had planned on making the points up to Julian by giving him a bounty on another question he had already answered, BUT, since there is a positive vote count, I'll keep it as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To arrive at the new combination,

> Jerry takes the previous combination, multiplies it by $5$, then adds either $1$ or $3$, depending on whether the previous combination was even or odd (respectively).

The next combination is

> $406901041\times 5+3=2034505208$.

Comment: I think you got it, just curious what do you use to solve this in such a short time?

Comment: Damn. I thought this question would be too hard and I'd need to give more hints, and maybe even a bounty. This is correct, but the way you arrived there is not exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: If you start at 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, ... 1/49152, and look only at the non-repeating digits of the decimals that repeat, for example, the 1 from 1/6, then you get a sequence. From that sequence, take the first instance of length 1, then the first instance of length 2, etc. Finally, remove any leading zeros.

Comment: @Alex The combinations are getting larger, and I noticed each combination was about 5 times as big as the previous one. I computed how far each combination was from 5 times the previous one, and I noticed a pattern.

Comment: @JLee Oh, interesting. It's not obvious to me that your description and my description will determine the same sequence (though it certainly looks like they will).

Comment: @JLee guess I'm not smart enough to even understand your answer... 1/6 = 0.166666667 -> non repeating digits = 0.167, then what do you do?

Comment: @Alex 1/6 = 0.1666666 and the 6 repeats forever, but the **1** does not. In 1/12, the **08** does not repeat, but the rest of the number does. My intended answer involved the sequence of each of these strings of non-repeating decimals that are at the beginning of repeating decimals.

Comment: Actually there is no guarantee this answer is correct.  The next code could be anything.  For example, every 14th number could reset to 51.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer here

> the 4 last digits should be 5208
>  last digit alternates between 1 and 8, so the current is 8
>  second to last digit alternates between 0 and 4, so the current is 0
>  third to last digit alternates between 0 and 2, so the current is 2
>  fourth to last digit is in the 1, 5, 6, 0 suite and start over, so the current is 5

I haven't found yet the end of the pattern, but that might help others

Answer (score -2):

The question is too easy.  All you have to do is look at the midway point such as 5208 and see that the next number is roughly 5 times that and then just play with the small difference to get it to match.  I think this person deserves to have his safe cracked for picking such as bad algorithm.

Comment: well, i agree with you!

Comment: Ha ha, OP agrees with me and I still get downvoted.  What a joke this site is.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but honestly, your answer didn't add any value, and just came off as negative. Better (for us **and** for you) would have been to just find another puzzle that you would enjoy. If you had read through the comments on the question and the accepted answer, you would have already known the story behind this puzzle, how I intended it to be one way, and then found it uninteresting when I saw it solved another way, which turned out to be too simple. I planned to delete it, but it had a few upvotes at the time, so I left it.

Comment: Why didn't it add any value?  What if I had answered first before anyone else, then would have it added value?  Nobody in real life would ever be so careless to use such a simple code for a safe.  Also, why would he post previous codes where people can see them?  He could just keep a list in his wallet instead.  The question is not "real world".

Comment: When you post an answer that is not an answer, then people routinely down-vote it. You are lucky that yours has only one down-vote. You had a comment, and instead of posting it as a comment, you posted it as an answer. It is perfectly OK to not like questions. Go ahead, down-vote it if you'd like. That is what life is all about. There will always be an infinite amount of stuff that you don't like or approve of or would do differently. The solution: acknowledge it, and move on to something that interests you. The quicker you can make this transition, the happier you will be.

Comment: How could a correct answer have no value?  I stated each successive combination is 5x the previous combination within a small difference.  So for example, multiply 41 by 5 and get 205 but since I stated a small difference, first try 206, then 207, then 208.  This will NOT send a text to Jerry's phone cuz it is not 3 failed attempts in a row.  Whoever downvoted me needs to go back and fix that.